# Estimate from above, below on second order Matrix ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, estimation

Consider the following ODE on $\mathbb{C}^n$:
\begin{equation}
 X''(t) = R(t) X(t),
\end{equation}
where $X(t)$ is a $n\times n$ complex-valued matrix and $R(t)$ has the following properties:positive definite, symmetric, smooth components.

I would like to obtain an estimate for $||X(t)||$ of the following kind

\begin{equation}
e^{\sqrt{\lambda_{\min}}t} \lesssim \|X(t)\| \lesssim e^{\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}}t},
\end{equation}
where the constants depend on the initial values $X(0), X'(0)$ and $\lambda_{\min},\lambda_{\max}$ are the positive square roots of the minimum and maximum eigenvalue of $R(t)$, uniformly in time. Precisely

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{\min} = \min_{t\in [0,T]} \lambda_i(t), \quad \lambda_i(t) \in \sigma(R(t)),\: i=1,\ldots,n,
\end{equation} 
$\sigma$is the spectrum. The same goes for $\lambda_{\max}$.

Note: I already proved the upper bound. I am not sure the lower bound holds with the positive sign. Estimates with $e^{-\lambda_{\min}t},e^{-\lambda_{\max}t}$ are OK as well.

Note(bis): I am not completely sure the lower bound holds in general but I was unable to provide a counterexample, so if you have one, that would be OK as well.

EDIT: as mentioned by @loup blanc, the result does not hold in general. Indeed the lower bound fails to be true. I encountered a result (Katchalov, Inverse spectral boundary problems Lemma 2.56)  that gives conditions under which X(t) is non degenerate. Precisely, in addition to what I have assumed above, $X'(0)(X(0))^{-1}$ has to be symmetric and with positive definite imaginary part. 
The results fails to give a quantitative bound, which is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $t>0$. I agree with the superior bound in the form $ \|X(t)\| \leq Ce^{\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}}t}$. Yet, the inferior bound may be $0$. See for example, the case $n=1,R=1$ and  $X(t)=e^t-2e^{-t}$.

EDIT. Answer to @MBerra. You cannot obtain a lower bound that depends on a sole eigenvalue.

To see that, consider the case $n=2$ and $R$ is the constant matrix $diag(a^2,b^2)$ where $a\not=b$. Then $X(t)=(ue^{at}+ve^{-at},pe^{bt}+qe^{-bt})$ and $||X(t)||^2=|ue^{at}+ve^{-at}|^2+|pe^{bt}+qe^{-bt}|^2$; the minimum in $t\geq 0$, depends on $a,b$; moreover there is no formula for a lower bound that depends only on $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I agree in case the initial values are real. What if those are complex? For example, x(0) = 1, x'(0) = i? There's a result (Katchalov, Inverse Boundary spectral problems) about the riccati DRE that states X(t) is invertible if the inital values are of the above mentioned form.

Comment: Multiple  $X (0),X'(0) $ by a complex number.

Comment: (the key is not having both complex. The condition is X'(0)X(0)^(-1) symmetric with positive definite imaginary part.

Comment: You spend your time. Your supplementary condition implies that $X(t)$ is never $0$. Yet, $||X(t)||$ may  reach its minimum for a small value of $t$. In these conditions,  all eigenvalues of $R$ have the same importance. In particular, there is no general formula for a $>0$  lower bound of $||X(t)||$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "all eigenvalues have the same importance"?

Comment: I accepted the answer, because what @loup blanc says it is certainly true. But, I would argue though that in the case you explained, I can always limit from below the solution by taking the system with min(a^2,b^2) diag(1,1), right? (see for example gil' Stability of Finite and Infinite Dimensional Systems, chap 4). In this way, only the minimum eigenvalue is in place. Would this change your answer?